# NoSQL DB that allows > 100MB in JSON objects and no restrictions on key names?

Tags: json, database, nosql, cloud

We are looking for a NoSQL DB that:

- Stores JSON objects greater than 100MB
- Allows special characters in key names (/\<>:?*)

MongoDB doesn't allow those special characters and Couchbase doesn't allow JSON over 20MB. Is there one that exists?

Comment: We are going with CouchDB. We really just needed it to allow special characters, particularly ".". After playing around with their "views", seems to be a great DB, definitely recommend for those looking for a DB that is flexible.